# Continuous Integration - How to run npm install on offline server

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, ansible

Our continuous integration system uses ansible playbooks to deploy our repo (including node modules) to a list of servers as specified in our ansible host file.  We have numerous environments which are configured in individual host files.  Jenkins is our build server which is used to kick of each ansible run on a schedule.  One of the tasks in the ansible playbook is npm install.

Our problem arises because only one of the environments is offline, so when the playbook performs the npm install task on this particular environment (read "host file"), it fails due to lack of internet connectivity.

I've seen lots of answers on how to get around this manually, but the whole point of our continuous integration system is to run automatically, and consistently (from environment to environment).  So I don't want to introduce a bunch of workarounds in the playbook and/or repo to bundle up, etc. the node modules just to get around this particular hosts offline issue.

Since this is a lower enviroment, I am willing to do something specific in advance, as a one time step, on this server in order to bypass this issue.  But since the playbook tasks tar up all existing files under the user account in a rollback zip file prior to installing the new code, anything I introduce on the server under this user account will be essentially removed (with the exception of . files and directories).

So, how to us CI to run npm install on single offline server without manual intervention?

Comment: we are heavily used nodejs apps. the second solution that @James has mentioned, we worked like that. If you need help on that, I can guide you on this even step by step

Comment: To further elaborate on the issue/solution - because of frequent changes to our package.json, the npm install command could change from one run to the next.  So it could be important to run it with each build. So my direction is to run it on the Jenkins server (which DOES have internet connectivity) after the cloning, and prior to kicking off Ansible to deploy to the host.

Comment: we are doing the same, checkout the code, do npm install, archive the code and upload to storage location, then kick the ansible job and it download it form the storage server and do the remaining tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ansible but the problem you're experiencing isn't uncommon, and there are definitely automated ways of solving it e.g.

- Setup a local NPM registry e.g. [sinopia](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia) and configure this as your default registry. Nodes with no internet access will receive the latest cached version of the package (presuming it was previously downloaded by a node)
- Run `npm install` once, package the nodes up and share the artifacts across the environments

Personally, I prefer and advocate the second solution because:

- Faster CI runs (only one download)
- Package version is guarenteed across all environments (although strict versioning would also solve this)

Comment: I think we're going to go with your 2nd suggestion - that way it's a frozen implementation of the dependencies and repeatable across all environments.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to setup an internal NPM registry, so that your offline Jenkins server can talk to your internal NPM, however keeping this in sync with the public NPM repository would likely be a nightmare, presenting a number of problems.

You need to allow "outbound only" internet access to this Jenkins server in order for this to work effectively without workarounds.

Comment: So our jenkins server in this situation is only used to pull the repo locally and it's not performing any shell commands other than to kick off the ansible playbook.  Also, jenkins does have access to the internet, just not the node being deployed to. So when ansible ssh's to the node it needs to have access to run the npm install task. Our other envs don't have this issue, so don't want to bog down the playbook with unnecessary tasks if we don't have to.